# How to prevent a man in the middle attack in https server to server communication

Tags: asp.net, security

We will be connecting to a web service over https. This will be triggered in the background if a user performs a certain action.

The link will be between the server and the web-service though - the user will not be aware of it.

As there is no user there to see the certificate come up with an error - because this is server to server - how can we mitigate a man in the middle attack between the two servers? What would happen in the code if one were tried and the certificate failed?

We are using ASP.NET.

Comment: the close as off-topic vote is bizarre.

Comment: @MK. - As written, this is both a design and security engineering question. There are better sites for the question because the details are important and it can be tricky to get right. The answers provided so far leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: @Jww what is the better site then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its up to you - you can specify your own validation behavior via

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx

Default implementation is very reasonable - throw an exception when validation fails.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a well-written HTTP client library to consume your web service, the calls will fail if the certificate validation fails.  Correct http client library will do full validation including making sure that hostname it connects to matches the subject name of the certificate, that CA is correct etc.  I would hope that .NET's implementation is correct in that regard, but you should definitely test and validate that default behavior is correct.

Comment: *" Correct http client library will ... that CA is correct etc"* - Not necessarily true. In the web security model, interception is a valid use case. Its the reason for the overrides in [RFC 7469](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7469.txt). The overrides allow the attacker to break known good pinsets. So you need to know the security model being used. *"I would hope that .NET's implementation is correct in that regard..."* - Nope, Microsoft uses the web security model.

Comment: @jww I'm totally failing to understand your point.  "the reason for overrides... the overrides allow the attacker to break known good pinsets.." I'm confused.   Also not clear what you mean by "web security model".  you talk about it like it is something specific one could refer to or use.  If you mean the status quo as of 5 years ago where no one validated TLS certs, yeah, that was broken and people are fixing it :)